# View on appstore option not available on appstoreconnect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Earlier there was an option as "View on AppStore" in itunesconnect to get the app url before publishing the app. Now it seems that apple has removed it. Anyone can help me getting the share url for my newly created app in AppStoreConnect. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Its because app is not live yet,

Comment: @rptwsthi, the option was available for both published and unpublished build some time before and now I have checked the same for published builds, its not present there also.

Answer (score 0):

It something like

```
https://itunes.apple.com/{countryCode}/app/{appName}/id{id_Here}?mt=8
```

for spaces in name replace with - suppose

> App name : wer dee
>
> country code : us
>
> id:5000345

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wer-dee/id5000345?mt=8